# Не могу локализовать Uber Ride Request Button. Вместо русского всё по-английски

Tags: ios, swift

Добавил в приложение [Uber Ride Request Button](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/button/ios). Всё работает, но язык кнопки - английский, поменять никак не получается. Русский есть в [списке поддерживаемых языков](https://developer.uber.com/docs/trip-experiences/guides/localization), на устройстве установлены язык и регион Россия.
Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: то есть, вы утверждаете, что все должно работать без написания какого либо кода на основании locale?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Мне кажется, именно так это и должно работать. Uber api осуществляет связь с сервером Uber и возвращает мне инфу о поездке. Вряд ли разработчик сам должен переводить все возможные ответы сервера.

Comment: ну если код писать не надо, и все должно работать само, то видимо есть смысл связаться с тех поддержкой uber

Comment: отправили на английский stackoverflow, там тоже никто не смог помочь

Comment: ну максимум что могу предложить - создайте минимальный пример, на котором это можно воспроизвести, попробуем посмотреть